# Aboardagem para uma melhor performance na busca de registros atualizados massivamente usando uma tabela secundária com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou utilizando o framework Laravel em um projeto e nele existe o model `Product`.

Neste sistema, também tenho uma API onde um dos endpoints recebe uma uma data e deve retornar os produtos alterados ou removidos dessa data em diante.

Na tabela `products` tenho a coluna `updated_at` sem índice.

Minha primeira abordagem para o endpoint citado acima, seria listar todos os produtos onde a coluna `updated_at` fosse maior ou igual a data passada por parâmetro para a API.

No entanto vejo um problema de performance ai (updated_at não tem índice) o que levou a pensar em outras abordagens.

O Laravel oferece o recurso de `Observer` e com esse recurso resolvi criar uma tabela secundária que receberia sempre as informações do `id` do produto que foi cadastrado, alterado ou removido.

Para isso eu teria o model `ProductSync` para inserir os ids dos produtos e a tabela product_sync teria um índice na coluna `created_at`

```php
class ProductObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the Product "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(Product $product)
    {
        ProductSync::create(['product_id' => $product->id]);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the Product "updated" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return void
     */
    public function updated(Product $product)
    {
        ProductSync::create(['product_id' => $product->id]);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the Product "deleted" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleted(Product $product)
    {
        ProductSync::create(['product_id' => $product->id]);
    }
}
```

Então eu faria um relacionamento `hasOne` com o model `Product`.

Porém descobri com essa abordagem tenho 2 problemas:

1) O Laravel não dispara os eventos para alterações massivas.

2) Registros duplicados na tabela `product_sync` (poderia resolver com um `select distinct`)

Uma outra abordagem que pensei foi criar uma trigger direto no banco de dados para popular a tabela `product_sync`, mas o problema de performance pode ser grande para atualizações em massa.

Outra abordagem quando houver alterações em massa seria jogar a rotina de criar os registros na tabela `product_sync` em uma fila e ela faria o trabalho aos poucos.

Levando em consideração que não posso por índice na coluna `updated_at` da tabela `products`, como eu posso resolver esse problema para alterações massivas?

Por exemplo, imagina que eu tenho na tabela `products` 5 milhões de registros e uma alteração em massa fosse mudar 75 mil registros?

```php
Product::whereIn('category_id', [421, 923, 1321])->update([
    'status' => 'paused'
]);
```

Comment: Porque não adiciona o índice  ?

Comment: A ideia é usar outra tabela.

Comment: Você poderia colocar o índice e testar, mas, esse volume de dados é real? se for o problema é como poderia melhorar essas atualizações, é isso mesmo o quantidade de registros?

Comment: Produtsync só aceita a id do produto? Como você ta enviando dados para o create pelo que vejo você passa o Model Products e passa id pra ele, mas não deveria passar um Request para receber de uma view?